# Create fancyhdr footer with something like: \lfoot{\centering{Centered to the left}}

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, positioning

[image: A footer with text seemingly centered to the left and right]

How can I create a footer like this one? It appears to be text centered in the left half of the page, and in the right half of the page. I tried, eg., using `fancyhdr` with:

```
\lfoot{\centering{some text}}
```

but this just centered the text across the whole page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{\hfill Specific Arms \hfill Page \thepage\hfill}
```

or

```
\lfoot{\makebox[0.5\linewidth]{Specific Arms}\makebox[0.5\linewidth]{Page \thepage}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Herbert. I was using your answer, then I found:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize \hskip 0pt plus .25 fill Research Strategy \hskip 0pt plus .5 fill  Page \thepage\hskip 0pt plus .25 fill }
```

Which is slightly more complicated but it allows you to adjust the amount of space in each open space.

Comment: that is what `\makebox` does ...